# Blender hair problem: Cycles viewport rendering is different from final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, bezier-curves, hair

I'm having a weird problem where the hair at the tips of my mesh look like they're exploding. I have no idea why this is or why it only shows up in the render. I also have some strands that are darker and thinner for no reason. Does anyone have a solution to this?  I have no modifiers on the hair mesh currently.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this hair being made with particles too or only meshes+ textures?

Comment: I used the particles to create hair, and then turned those curves into meshes

Comment: verify if the subdivision of the mesh that emits the particles in the preview is the same in the render.

Comment: There actually isn't any subdivision, the modifier tab is empty

Comment: Can you share the file? it would help to find the problem.